# Google Chrome Cannary: Icons isn't appearing

Tags: google-chrome

I'm working using the Google Chrome Cannary for some time. With the last update (Version 64.0.3268.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)) I loosed every icon on the browser:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just wait for new version. I've got this problem too. Canary is unstable branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update *Google Chrome Version 64.0.3269.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)* solved the problem.